# How to fix error Device Chrome Not Configured When Trying to Run Android Simulator Script on Mac?

Tags: android, macos, appium

I get a device chrome not configured error when I try to run an android simulator script on my Mac.
I used the Mac for both IOS and Android testing.
Can you anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks.

I'm using El Capitan OS and appium version 1.4.11.

I installed Appium with these steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/appium/appium.git
2. Type in terminal $ ./reset.sh --ios --real-safari --code-sign 'code signing identity' --profile 'retrieved profile identity code'
3. I previously installed the android sdk only without android studio.

Error:
`unknown20C9D0E03E3B:~ mac$ '/usr/local/bin/node' '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium-doctor.js'
Running iOS Checks
✖ Could not detect Mac OS X Version
Appium-Doctor detected problems. Please fix and rerun Appium-Doctor.

ERROR:
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Device chrome not configured yet) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.33 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'unknown20C9D0E03E3B', ip: '192.168.1.71', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
`

Comment: Was this resolved? I ran into the same problem.....

Comment: I haven't worked on this lately, but I recall after installing most of the android apis including the very early ones in SDK Manager then it solved a lot of the Android problems. You can't just install the latest Android Version SDK, you have to install the earlier ones too. I think it is mandatory to install something in the teens like 16,18, etc... I don't remember. You can look up the requirements on whats needed to be installed to operate on Appium. Hope this helps.